# Can't use any of the iWork apps

Tags: pages, keynote, iwork, numbers

I'm unable to use any of the apps included in the iWork package. If I try to open any one of them, the app opens but I can't perform any action. I click on the bar menu items to see that even 'About Numbers' or 'Open' items are greyed out.

I tried reinstalling the apps(even deleting them with AppCleaner so that every app item gets deleted) several times with no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you check in Console to see whether there are any log messages for the applications you are trying? If you use the filter box in the top-right corner to filter on Pages or Numbers I'm assuming there will be messages there.

Comment: Tried that for iWork, Pages, Numbers, Keynote and got nothing in return.

Comment: I don't know what happened but something changed and now I can use all of the iWork apps. 